# Cannot change color in cell of table in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use javascript so as to manipulate the `<td>` tab inside table with id’s `<td>` is '#DeviceType .Redis'. But, the problem is that the snippet code below can be change color of table cell which I want to change.

```
$('#DeviceType .Redis').css('background-color', '')
                    .css('background-color', 'red');
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem. Thanks so much.

Comment: can you post your html too?

Comment: Add your HTML to this question.

Comment: George Pant, JohnAtNotion : I think html code in this case is not necessary, because of the id and the html code can be generate automatively. Best regard !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your id’s `<td>` invalidate. In html, it can’t accept period in the id identifier. For example: the name of your `id = '#DeviceType .Redis'` must change `‘.’` to another notation such as `‘-’, ‘_’` … and the name of id as follow id = `'#DeviceType_Redis'`